# How to fix Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\Phantom' when create react app[CLOSE]

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm installing react and want to create my first project on react but I'm got something problem while install it. how to fix it ?

```
Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\Phantom'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:98:27)
    at errorHandler (F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
    at F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
    at cb (F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:225:22)
    at F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:263:24
    at F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13
    at f (F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20)
F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:98
  var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:98:27)
    at process.errorHandler (F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:123:25)
Install for create-react-app@latest failed with code 7
```

that's the error said

Comment: Where are you creating the app? It's always better to do it in an empty directory

Comment: i'm creating the app in new folder which is in E:\LearnReact directory. that is an empty directory

Answer (score 4):

I executed the following steps:

1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
2. `npm install -g create-react-app`
3. `npx create-react-app the-name-of-your-app`