# Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir C:\users\computer-name in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create `react` project , for that I installed `node` and `npm` following this [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) link.

Now when I `run` the following command

`npx create-react-app my-app`

It gives me

> Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\Mehmood'
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
>       at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:98:27)
>       at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:77:20
>       at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:225:22)
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:263:24
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13
>       at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
>       at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20)
>   C:\Program Files\nodejs\node\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:98
>     var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
>                             ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
>       at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:98:27)
>       at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
>       at process.emit (events.js:198:13)
>       at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27)
>   Install for create-react-app@latest failed with code 7

I have gone through [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4745) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55399213/11625619)

I uninstalled the old `node`, deleted all the files, and installed new `node`, and then tried to create `react project` but still I'm facing the same `issue`.

**Note:**  Few days ago, I made some changes to my `environment variables`, I don't know will that effect some `settings` ?

Please leave your precious comments.

Thank you.

Comment: I have the exact problem. did you succeed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I npm uninstall -g create-react-app then installed it again and it worked for me!

Comment: It is not an answer in question he already explained to uninstall and install again.